# Two solutions to a first-order ODE?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, roots, indefinite-integrals

I'm supposed to solve the equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=100-y$$
Now, by taking the right-hand expression to the left and the dx to the right, there's the obvious solution $$\ln{(100-y)}=-x+c_1$$
But I did this; $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-(y-100)$$$$\frac{dy}{y-100}=-dx$$$$\ln{(y-100)}=-x+c_2$$
Which is very much not the same. It's a first-order differential equation, and there should only be one root, so my method is obviously faulty.

Can someone help me with the why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $$\int \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx = \ln\color{red}|x\color{red}| + C$$ Do not forget about the *absolute value*.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you clarify one thing, though; going by this, we get the solution $y=50e^{-x}+100\forall y>100$ and $y=-50e^{-x}+100\forall y<100$. However, both the solution to the question and WolframAlpha only consider the latter as a solution. What's the problem with the first?